# Laravel TDD assertSee returns true on NULL object

Tags: php, laravel, tdd

Whenever I try to test some object property which does not exists (which is actually null), tests passes when using `$this->assertSee($record->someNonExistingProperty)`:

```
public function test_a_user_should_be_able_to_see_a_consumer_address()
{
    $this->get(route('users.index'))->assertSee($this->user->address);
}
```

`$this->user->address` does not exists, but test returns green

What's wrong with that assertion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be this, it is asserting it can see nothing/everything.

If `$this->user->address` return `null` then your assertion would equate to this:

```
$this->get(route('users.index'))->assertSee(null);
```

---

I would also do an assertion on your objects property too. Like so:

```
$this->assertTrue($this->user->address !== null);
$this->get(route('users.index'))->assertSee($this->user->address);
```

---

The documentation on assert see states it looks for a string and will escape any value it is given

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/http-tests#assert-see

Comment: yeah, I can use `$this->assertNotNull($this->user->address);` as a pre-safe, but I'm not sure why "assertSee" can pass even though it shouldn't

Comment: So it depends on what `assertSee()` is checking for. If it is trying to match a string then `null` would be the equivalent of `''` which will be everywhere in your DOM. I've never tried checking that i can see `null` in a test haha

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for this is to use a null coalescing operator like:

```php
$response ->assertSeeText($this->user->address ?? '**No Address Field**')
```

This part `$this->user->address ?? '**No Address Field**'` checks if there is a `$this->user->address` and if not returns `**No Address Field**` - as long as your view does not show this text it will fail.

So basically change the text of `**No Address Field**` to something you want to see in the test results to identify the missing key, but is not present in the view.